# PHP MongoDB импорт файл больше чем 16 mb

Tags: php, yii2, mongodb

Привет всем! У меня проблема с MongoDB точнее не могу импортировать js файл с размером 55 mb. Искал везде но не нашел конкретную решению. Есть кто с такими проблемами сталкивался ?подробное описывайте плз я только начал изучать YII2 и MongoDB  буду рад за любое помощь. спасибо зарание

[image: Вот такой exception выдает]

Answer (score 1):

Размер одного документа в монге не может превышать 16мб. Это ограничение можно убрать, но только перекомпиляцией самой монги. Сомневаюсь что есть смысл это делать.